# How to automate a database search on a website from a third party website?

Tags: search, website, database, web-development, wordpress

My users will be uploading products on my website which are registered by a government organisation. This government organisation has created an online database of these products which is free to search (but has not provided the ability to download). I was wondering if there was any way to automatically search this other database before my users have upload their product as a means to check that their product actually exists? This is in order to create integrity on the website.

I understand how the match it but was wondering if it was possible to automatically search online database from another site and pull data from it?

Cheers in advance

Comment: Is the database web based?  Check the terms of service, if they don't forbid it you could do web scrapping.  In some cases you can programmatically emulate the visiting of a website.  The best case would if the government provided an API then someone could write a program to do it easily.

Comment: Yes that database is web based their website hosts a search engine for it, thanks for the web scrapping tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not provided specifics, so I can't answer with specifics, but [CURL](https://curl.haxx.se/) is very often used to do this kind of "scraping" - it basically lets you control how to get web requests, and can even do things like log you in, set a browser string, handle HTTPS, follow redirects etc.

If your curent site uses PHP,  there are [PHP module](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)s for it, so its easy to integrate.